# How to exit a ROS node on keyboard interrupt?

Tags: python, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you write a Python ROS node so that it exits in response to a KeyboardInterrupt exception?

I have a trivial node like:

```
class MyNode:

    def __init__(self):
        while 1:
            do stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('mynode')
    MyNode(rospy.get_name())
```

But pressing ^C doesn't stop it. I see my "^C" interrupt character appear in the output of my "do stuff" code, but the node continues to run, almost as though it's not running in the main thread.

I tried implementing a `rospy.on_shutdown()` callback, but it's never called in response to a KeyboardInterrupt.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238857/how-to-exit-a-ros-node-on-keyboard-interrupt?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-07-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-07-06**:
`rospy.on_shutdown()` callback has to be called before SIGKILL. Can you please show your implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The publisher in the [rospy publisher and subscriber tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber) demonstrates how to do this: your infinite loop needs to check `rospy.is_shutdown()`:

```
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    # do stuff
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2